# Keras Time Series Transformer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have this code from Keras time series classification with a Transformer model:

```
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Attention and Normalization
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size,
        num_heads=num_heads,
        dropout=dropout)(inputs, inputs)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)

    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(res)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)

    return x + res
```

If I try to change the `Conv1D` to `ConvLSTM1D` layer, I get this error:

```
Input 0 of layer "conv_lstm1d_27" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 24, 4)
```

I changed the shape of dataset to `(1354, 4, 24, 10)` but it doesn't help. I can't understand the issue with shape and dimensions here.

Comment: What is the shape of the input tensor that produces the above error?

Comment: input_shape = x_train.shape[1:], this is the shape of dataset (5416, 24, 10)

Comment: If you check the documentation for [ConvLSTM1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM1D), you'll see that under `Call arguments`, tensorflow expects the tensor to be 4D. Yours is 3D.

Comment: I tried to change it to (1354, 4, 24, 10), nothing has changed

Comment: It's because you are not returning the full sequence. Add `return_sequences=True` to your `ConvLSTM1D` instantiation.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. But now another problem "Input 0 of layer "global_average_pooling1d_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 5416, 24, 10)" So I need to return 3D tensor to feed global_average_pooling1d.